# H2: getArray returns only one element

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, h2

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
... 
  "columns" ARRAY NOT NULL,
...
);
```

I inserted elements in array manually via H2 web console:

```
INSERT INTO "mytable"(..."columns"...) VALUES
(...,'{''col1:uuid'',''col2:id'',''col3:firstName'',''col4:middleName'',''col5:lastName''}',...);
```

Now I try to get array of elements from java

```
Object[] colArray=(Object[]) rs.getArray("columns").getArray();
System.out.println("Test:"+colArray.length);//returns 1. all columns are in one string.
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert into the column with type ARRAY use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO
              "mytable"("columns")
       VALUES
       ( 
           (
               'col1:uuid',
               'col2:id',
               'col3:firstName',
               'col4:middleName',
               'col5:lastName'
           )
       );
```

Check your data with

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH("columns") FROM "mytable"
```

Comment: No, it didn't help. In resultset I have only one row with all columns.

Comment: I think the problem is how I insert array to table.

Comment: Ok, I see. Did you try insert as from the docs `INSERT INTO "mytable"("columns") VALUES 
( 

('col1:uuid','col2:id','col3:firstName', 'col4:middleName','col5:lastName')

);`
then see the result with
`SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH("columns") fROM "mytable"`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edit the answer. The problem was in replacing `{}` to `()`. Is this general SQL rule for inserting array or H2?

Comment: ty. I think so, I read it @ http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type where it says `Use a value list (1, 2)`. The trick is to put values 1, 2 into the ( ) :).

Comment: So, it is H2 specific? Sorry, I didn't understand from your answer.

Comment: I think it should be specific. I am not a big pro in database management systems. I found http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility "Where possible, H2 supports the ANSI SQL standard, and tries to be compatible to other databases. There are still a few differences however." afaik ANSI 92 has no ARRAY support. What dbms are you asking about for the support of array type?

Comment: I plan to do my application for H2 and PgSQL. So I wanted to understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83282/discussion-between-spookiecookie-and-jimjim2000).